# Automatic width calculation for video resizing in FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Right now I'm using this to try and scale a 720p video down to 480p, the problem is the automatic width is selecting an odd number.

I am currently using `-vf "scale=trunc(oh*a*2)/2:480` and it still selects 853 for the width.  Any tips?

Comment: Never mind, solved it myself with `-vf "scale=trunc(oh*a/2)*2:480"`

Comment: You should post that as an answer below. Self-answering is encouraged here.

Comment: @Peter: Good workaround with truncate function. Similar effect can be achieved by floor & ceiling functions. A neat way to kill this _**odd**_ problem is to add `-2` instead of `-1` for ffmpeg to _**automatically**_ calculate the omitted value and make sure it's divisible by 2 (by adding 1 if value is odd), instead of you calculating manually.

Answer (score 11):

### The problem

The scale filter in `ffmpeg` can be provided just one dimension and it can automatically calculate the undeclared dimension if you use `-1` as a value, such as with `-vf scale=640:-1`, but that can end of being an odd number.

`ffmpeg` uses libx264 to encode H.264 video. This encoder requires mod2 for width and height for 4:2:0 chroma subsampling; meaning that the width and height must be divisible by 2.

### The solution

Use `-2`. It will:

- Automatically calculate the correct value in relation to the declared dimension while preserving the aspect ratio.
- Make the output divisible by 2. It will adjust the output if necessary.

### Example

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vf scale=-2:480 output.mp4
```

### Also see

- [FFmpeg scale filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale)
- [FFmpeg H.264 Video Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)